# Laravel eloquent Select statement set null column defualt value to 0 or blank

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating a query and executing it in my project. I want to set null column value to 0 in select statement.

We need to set null to blank or zero. See below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use model casting, using "if" statement https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts

Comment: Thats a good answer but i think OP requested he wanted to excecute the query in the sql server

Comment: @aleksandra.k376 Please Explain with an example.

Comment: @KaushalPatel What is your table name that you want to update?

Comment: @workservice  we don't need a table column update. we need model casting for my work. I make rest API so the null value does not handle by other platform. So I need blank or 0 value instead of null

Comment: @KaushalPatel based on your first question you said : I am creating a query and executing it in sqlserver so i assumed you wanted it to run in the sql server

Comment: @workservice Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` table_name`SET`column_name `= 0 WHERE column_name is NULL`

Edit: You can add as many columns as needed by adding a comma `,`